# Check particular identifier is present in the other data frame or not

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
val df1 = Seq(("[1,10,20]", "bat","43243"),("[20,4,10]","mouse","4324432"),("[30,20,3]", "horse","4324234")).toDF("id", "word","userid") 

val df2 = Seq((1, "raj", "name"),(2, "kiran","name"),(3,"karnataka","state"),(4, "Andrapradesh","state")).toDF("id", "name", "code")
```

**Explanation**:

I have two dataframes  `df1` & `df2`. `df1` is having `id` column which is having a list of ids.

I need to check any one of the ids is present in the `df2` dataframe.

**Conditions**

if `id` is present in the `df2` `id` column and if the code is `state` then get the `name` of the particular `id` from the df2 and create a new data frame with `name` column

**Expected Output**

```
id        |     word    |  userid   | name

-------------------------+-----------------------

[30,20,3] |  "horse"    | "4324234" | "karnataka"  
[20,4,10] |  "mouse"    | "4324432" | "Andrapradesh"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the `id` column first by converting it to an array and applying `explode`. Then you can apply a normal join operation between the DataFrames.

For example:

```scala
val df1 = Seq(("[1,10,20]", "bat","43243"),("[20,4,10]","mouse","4324432"),("[30,20,3]", "horse","4324234")).toDF("id", "word","userid") 
val df2 = Seq((1, "raj", "name"),(2, "kiran","name"),(3,"karnataka","state"),(4, "Andrapradesh","state")).toDF("id", "name", "code")

val flattenDf1 = df1.
  select(
    col("id"),
    expr("""split(regexp_replace(id, "\\[|\\]",""), ",")""").as("idArray"), col("word"),
    col("userid")).
  withColumn("id_", explode(col("idArray"))).
  drop("idArray")

df2.as("df2").
  join(
    flattenDf1.as("df1"),
    col("df2.id") === col("df1.id_")).
  filter("code = 'state'").
  select("df1.id", "word", "userid", "name").
  show
// Result: 
// +---------+-----+-------+------------+
// |       id| word| userid|        name|
// +---------+-----+-------+------------+
// |[30,20,3]|horse|4324234|   karnataka|
// |[20,4,10]|mouse|4324432|Andrapradesh|
// +---------+-----+-------+------------+
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't is possible without using regex ? ``` expr("""split(regexp_replace(id, "\\[|\\]",""), ",")""").as("idArray"), col("word"),
   ```

Comment: If the column `id` is an actual string with square brackets, I think you have to apply some string manipulation to get the actual values in the list into an array. Then you can flatten the dataframe or apply an UDF like in the other answer you have. Is using a regex an issue? If it is, please explain why to see what alternatives we have.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use UDF as a condition in the join:

```
val arrayJoin = udf { 
   (a: WrappedArray[Int], v: Int) => a.contains(v) 
}

val result = df1
      .join(df2.as("df2"), arrayJoin(df2("id"), df1("id"))) //join using udf
      .drop("df2.id", "df2.code") //drop unnecessary columns
```

Comment: This solution might work and may be more elegant than mine. However, not sure if he has an array or a string representing an array. In the latter case the string would have to be converted to an array before, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Using UDF is right option ? https://medium.com/@mrpowers/spark-user-defined-functions-udfs-6c849e39443b